# Optimistic and optimist

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I’m afraid that I couldn’t distinguish with clarity whether to apply the noun *optimist* or the adjective *optimistic*.

Possessing a Brazilian Portuguese background language, in which we don’t differentiate those specific words, there is not a single time that I don’t stop and think about which word would be better.

What’s the difference between the following sentences?

> I am an optimist.
>
> I am optimistic...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We would say *I am very optimistic* when you might say *Eu estou muito otimista*, while we would say *I am very much the optimist* when you might say *No fundo eu sou otimista*.

That is, you would use the noun when you are expressing a permanent trait inherent to the person (hence *ser* in Portuguese), but you would use the adjective when you are expressing a passing condition (hence *estar* in Portuguese).

This may be over-simplifying a bit, but I’ve deliberately explained it using Portuguese equivalents because I hope this will make it easiest for you in particular to understand the distinction you are asking about.

Saying that you are an optimist means you are an optimistic person in general, but saying that you are optimistic about something means that right now you are looking at that thing as being likely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perhaps the second sentence should be rewritten to *I'm optimistic...*, thus implying the necessity of some object to be optimistic for. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, the second sentence should probably be *I’m optimistic...* as you have suggested, being optimistic **about** something or other.